# SQL query in C# in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public Availableopt(ref SqlConnection nsc, String ac, String nonac, String sit1, String sleep1, String fromopt, String toopt)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        // String s = "select * from Available where From = @fromopt ";
        SqlCommand ncd = new SqlCommand("select * from Available", nsc);
        SqlDataAdapter sdan1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sdan1.SelectCommand = ncd;

        DataTable db = new DataTable();
        sdan1.Fill(db);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = db;
        grid.DataSource = bs;

        sdan1.Update(db);
    }
```

In the above code, the `where` clause is not working in select query.

```
select * from Available where from = 'ahmedabad';
```

There is a `SqlException` on the line

```
sqldataadapter.fill(datatable)
```

except `where` clause the SQL query is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Please always include the error/exception message you get, rather than *"there is some sqlexception"*. I't will not always be so obvious from your code what's going wrong as in this case.

Comment: okay! next time i will look out for this. anyways, thank you

Answer (score 2):

`From` is a keyword in SQL. If you have a column with that name (which was a bad idea), you can use:

```
select * from Available where [From] = @fromopt
```

You should also [set the parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) `@fromopt`:

```
ncd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromopt", fromopt);
```

Comment: thanks @Kobi . it is working now 
and sorry for mistakes in asking question. next time i will look out.